# What signal QListView sends when is about to hide

Tags: c++, qt, listview

In my code I do have to do manually:

```
   /*This works but there must be a better way*/

        listView->hide();//INSTEAD OF THIS I'D RATHER SEND A SIGNAL CAUSING    
LISTVIEW TO UPDATE -  
 update(), viewport()->update, repaint() doesn't work,
```

Basically I have a listView in which I'm displaying selection of files. After pressing ok this dialog closes. When I open this dialog again and pick another set of files the old ones are shown, and I have to hide and show listView in order to see newly selected files.

Comment: Is it about the files listed or about selection? If the former, which model implementation do you use?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld it is about files listed - they do not appear (change) after I open this dialog second time and select another set of files. I'm using as a model QAbstractListModel

Comment: The notification of your model might not work correctly then. Do you call begin/endInsertRows, begin/endRemoveRows, dataChanged etc?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yes, and I've also tested with modeltest and there were no errors detected. The strange thing is that calling hide and show in that order makes everything ok.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`clearSelection`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) slot. Connect it to the [`finished`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#finished) signal of your dialog.

Comment: thanks, have bit of a problem with connecting it: connect(QDialog,SIGNAL(finished()),listView,SLOT(clearSelection())); I'm getting error: primary expression expected before ',' token. I've tried to put 'this' instead of QDialog, then I'm getting error that finished is not defined in my class. Any thoughts on that ;)

Comment: finished has int as argument. In your dialog make the following connection: connect(this,SIGNAL(finished(int)),listView,SLOT(clearSelection()))

Comment: thanks for code. Unfortunately, doesn't do the trick. I still have to hide it and show it in order to update listView. What on earth else ;)

Comment: oh, and I'm getting following output from debug window: QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld as far as I'm concern no, I don't use mt;